# why my android application become slow in running?

Tags: android, inputstream

I'm using this code to display severl images from the internet

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView;
URL url = new URL(address);
InputStream content = (InputStream)url.getContent();
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(content , "src"); 
iv.setImageDrawable(d)
```

but the application became slow in running why ??
does the internet connection is the reason ??? or because i input several input stream to display each image???

Comment: Do you use threads to load the images? They are helpful when you need to load something from the Internet because the task can take quite a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create the InputStream and Drawable.createFromStream(...) asynchronously, either using an AsyncTask or using a separate thread and then update the ImageView using a Handler once they are complete. AsyncTask is prefereable.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: There is an example in the API page linked above, also on the Android Dev Blog http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Comment: Does this is useful ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905399/listitem-lazyload-asynctask-image-display-problem

Comment: but sorry for this question -i'm still a binginner- where to add this code ?? new Handler().post(new Runnable(){...